# My PC won't display anything on monitor?

Tags: desktop-computer

Anyone can help me? My computer is didn't display anything,it has power but no display I tried all this.

Put to Built In/ On board VGA = No display
CMOS CLR = No display
Remove Memory = No display
Remove Hard Disk Drive = No display
PSU = Good

Any ideas? is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: What does PSU = Good mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different monitor.

Try a different cable.

Try the monitor on a different machine.

If these fail, it's probably the board, and this means, new motherboard, IF the computer is actually booting up! Can you verify the machine is starting (do you hear it beep when it is turned on) because if no beeps, then the fault may not be the monitor!